# Google AppScript - get row values from master sheet and update existing sheets with that row value

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a master google sheet. It has a 2 row header and 211 data rows. I need to cycle through the master sheet and grab each row's data and udate an existing corresponding spreadsheet. The master sheet's second column has the name of the existing spreadsheets. These existing spreadsheets are in one folder and the master is in another.
I grab the specific data row from the master and then open the corresponding destination spreadsheet and update it with the static header and the data from the corresponding master row. However, my code does add the header rows but puts the wrong data row in the destination sheet.

For example; I have a folder with spreadsheets named C1, C2, C3  ... C211. In the master shee the second column has this c number per row and this is the reference to the name of the existing spreadsheets and the data from that row gets copied.
I hope this makes sense. Hopefully my code (that nearly works) will show what I am trying to do

```
function updateIndividualWorkbooks() {
  // Define the folder where the individual workbooks are located
  var folderId = "1HrzKS6yoxkcgAkBYz6wkDSYVjMLuXnKn"; // Replace with the actual folder ID
  
  // Get the master workbook
  var masterWorkbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var masterSheet = masterWorkbook.getSheetByName("ACKTRACKER"); // Name of Master Spreadsheet's sheet
  var data = masterSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Loop through all files in the folder
  
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folders.getFiles();

  var i = 3;

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

    const dataRows = masterSheet.getRange('A'+i+':CT'+i).getValues();
    //console.log("row values = : ",dataRows);

    // Open the individual workbook 
    var individualWorkbook = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    var individualSheet = individualWorkbook.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    
    // Update data in the individual workbook
    individualSheet.clear();
    
    // copy the first two header rows to destination spreadsheet
    individualSheet.getRange("A1:CT2").setValues(headerRows);
    
    // Delete the third row in the individual workbook so we start fresh
    individualSheet.deleteRow(3);
    
    individualSheet.getRange('A3:CT3').setValues(dataRows);

    i++;
  }
```

So when I run the code and do a console.log I can see that the header is correct and it adds it to the destination spreadsheets
When I do a console.log for the data row it shows the correct data for the row
When I run the script it adds the wrong data row to the destination spreadsheet.

So datarow 3 has c1 in the second column and I grab that data but when I run the script it seems to put a random row in, in this case it put c70's data.
What am I doing wrong?

Master spreadsheet example
The master spreadsheet has the first two rows as a header.
The next 211 rows has the following columns

| House | C number | username | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kenny | C1 | Joe | 70 |
| Mont | C2 | Bob | 30 |
| Bamboo | C3 | Tim | 60 |
| Phelps | C211 | Anne | 67 |

The folder with the destination spreadsheets has spreadsheets with the corresponding names c1 c2 c3 ... c21
So C3 spreadsheet would have the following after copying

House     C number     username     score
Bamboo       C3          Tim         60

I hope this helps (Thanks George for the tip)

Comment: The master spreadsheet has the first two rows as a header. The next 211 rows has the following columns
House        C number     username       score
kenny              C1                Joe               70
Mont               C2                Bob              30
Bamboo          C3                Tim              60
...
Phelps             C211             Anne            67

The folder with the destination spreadsheets has spreadsheets with the corresponding names
c1
c2
c3
...
c211

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Comment: George, 
when you say reproducible example what do you mean? The code supplied shows the range for the row I wish to copy. It shows the source spreadsheet (Master) that has the data I want to copy. It shows the destination folder where all the 211 spreadsheets are. Basically, I grab the data row from the master. The spreadsheet name column (C number) is sorted ascending order and the folder that has the destination spreadsheets has the file in the same order as the master spreadsheet. I gave an example of the data (minimal) that is to be retrieved. I am not sure what else I can supply
John

Comment: A dummy sheet would be best for a reproducible example so that the community can visualize the data that we are working on. In the dummy sheet you could include your desired output and the output that you are currently getting right now.

Comment: Thanks George. I added this (sort of) to my reply to Tainake. I have now added it to the original message. Much appreciated

Comment: headerRows is undefined

Comment: Cooper, my bad! I cut out some commented out code prior to posting and accidentally grabbed the headerRows declaration with them. I have re added this declaration. Thanks for letting me know